# Userform doesn't fill the sheet I want it to

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm new at VBA and would like to ask for help.

I have a userform that is supposed to help me fill a range in my worksheet.

It was working fine when I made it a few days ago.

Now though, it only adds an empty row to my table and I don't know where to look to find the error. I've been at it for a couple of hours now..

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim dl As Integer
Dim list_num As Integer
Dim ligne As Integer

list_num = Me.liste_com3.ListCount - 1

If Me.liste_com3.ListCount > 0 Then 'contrôl si la liste n'est pas vide
    
    If MsgBox("Voulez-vous enregistrer cette transaction ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    
        For ligne = 0 To list_num
        
            'ajouter nouvelle ligne dans le tableau
            Sheets(8).ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add
            'chercher numéro prochaine ligne du tableau
            dl = Sheets(8).Range("b9999").End(xlUp).Row
            
            'ajouter les infos dans la bdd
            Sheets(8).Range("Z" & dl) = Me.info1
            Sheets(8).Range("C" & dl) = Format(Me.txt_fac3, """FAC-""00000")
            Sheets(8).Range("D" & dl) = Format(CDate(Now()), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
            Sheets(8).Range("E" & dl) = Me.cbx_com
            
            'controler si c'est un fournisseur ou un client
            If Me.label_type = "Fournisseur :" Then
                Sheets(8).Range("F" & dl) = Me.cbx_type3
            Else
                Sheets(8).Range("G" & dl) = Me.cbx_type3
            End If
            
            'ajouter les données de la zone de liste
            Sheets(8).Range("H" & dl) = Me.liste_com3.List(ligne, 0)
            Sheets(8).Range("J" & dl) = Int(Me.liste_com3.List(ligne, 1))
        Next ligne
            
            MsgBox "Enregistrement réussi !"
            Unload Me
            ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
         
End If

Sheets(8).Range("K6:N9999").NumberFormat = "#,##0 [$XOF]"

End Sub

Private Sub liste_com3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Me.liste_com3.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    If MsgBox("Voulez-vous supprimer cette entrée ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Me.liste_com3.RemoveItem Me.liste_com3.ListIndex
        memo = memo - 1
    End If
End If
    End Sub

Private Sub opt_in_Click()
Me.label_type = "Fournisseur :"
Me.cbx_type3.RowSource = "col_fourni"
Me.cbx_com.RowSource = "col_comm"
Me.info1 = "Entrée"
End Sub

Private Sub opt_out_Click()
Me.label_type = "Client :"
Me.cbx_type3.RowSource = "col_clients"
Me.cbx_com.RowSource = ""
Me.info1 = "Sortie"
End Sub

Private Sub txt_fac3_Change()
If Not IsNumeric(txt_fac3) And txt_fac3 <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Veuillez entrer un nombre..."
    Me.txt_fac3 = ""
End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt_num3_Change()
'controle si numérique
If Not IsNumeric(txt_num3) And txt_num3 <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Veuillez entrer un nombre..."
    Me.txt_num3 = ""
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.label_info_3.Caption = "Mouvements"
End Sub
```

**Also the weird thing is that when I change the sheet that the userform is supposed to write to, it works. But not on the sheet I want.**

[This is a picture of my userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtMOS.png)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post only the relevant parts of code. Also, try to debug it using break points or F8 and see the exact moment it fails. Did you make sure your target sheet is still the 8th? Did you make sure `dl ` gets the correct number?

Comment: Hello! 
I'll try to reduce the code  -

No I did not try debugging because, technically, the code is not failing...I think?  -

Yes my target sheet is the 8th. Or is there another way I can reference it? I tried using the name but it didn't work...  -

I would like to know what you mean by **Did you make sure dl  gets the correct number?**  -

Comment: Your code does `dl = Sheets(8).Range("b9999").End(xlUp).Row` Is it getting `dl` the right number? If you debug it, you'll see it. Check [Debug code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code)

Comment: So, I just tried debugging by stepping into the code (thank you for the link!) but it doesn't find an error..

Comment: Have you rearranged your sheets?  `Sheets(8)` will look at the eighth sheet in tab order.  Best to refer to it by name `Sheets("MySheetName")`.  Same with `ListObjects` - `ListObjects("Table1")` rather than `ListObjects(1)`.

Comment: `dl = Sheets(8).Range("b9999").End(xlUp).Row` is the last row with content in Column B.  That's not the row you just added.  Try  `dl = Sheets(8).ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add.Range.Row`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I tried renaming too and it didn't work.

Comment: Hello again. In the end, I deleted the sheet and created a new one in it's placed and it worked! I'm really happy about that. I'm starting to think that I did something to the old one without realizing

Comment: Thank you @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns for your help and the insightful link

Comment: Thank you @DarrenBartrup-Cook for you suggestions and help

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams for your suggestions as well ^^